# How to make textbox fill available space in a flexible table?

Tags: css

How do I make a table that flexes between a min and max width, whilst 2 columns always stay the same width and a textbox in the third fills the available space.

It is almost working here. But the width on the fixed columns is being ignored when the table is small.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">
                Column 1
            </td>
            <td class="col2">
                Column 2
            </td>
            <td class="col3">
                Column 3
            </td>        
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>     
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td class="col2">
               fixed content
            </td>
            <td class="col3">
               fixed content
            </td>  
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


.col1 {
    max-width: 25em;
    min-width: 20em;
}

.col2, .col3 {
    width: 10em;
}

input {
    width: 100%
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4hty/1/)

Comment: Do you want the first col to resize?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is exactly what you wanted, but you need to make the table take  `100%` width, so it will grow on resize and the flexible first column with it. Unfortunately, `max-width` seems not to do anything here.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4hty/4/)

Comment: Unfortunately it is still collapsing the widths of the last two columns.